# What are the conditions which forge viewer measurement is enabled?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have uploaded many types of drawings to Forge.
eg) dwg, dxf, rvt, etc...
Some of these drawings were measurable and some were not.
Under what preconditions can I measure?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by when you said 'measurable' ? does measure extension load for only a few files or all files? is measure extension not working or giving wrong dimensions?

Comment: The measurement extension may not load. viewer version is 6.

Comment: please user the latest viewer version which is version 7.
Her's the migration guide: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/

Comment: Ok, I'll try it!